# Changing hard drive from dead computer

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, windows-vista, motherboard, computer-building

I have a Windows Vista Basic with intel processor that died with an extremely important file on it and I'm changing to a Windows Vista premium that uses AMD.

I have understood that as I have a different motherboard the hard drive will delete everything. What can I do?

The only solution I can think is to change the motherboard from my dead computer to the new one, what else can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstalling a windows operating system onto the new hard drive will erase everything.  Below are steps to copy the file off before reinstalling windows onto the hard drive.  If you're vista premium computer already has a hard drive in it, it won't erase any of the data just by plugging the hard drive into it.

If your computer died because the hardware died, you need to plug the hard drive into a working computer, and copy the file off.  If it died due to software (the operating system got corrupted), you can load up a live cd of ubuntu or something else to copy the file to a usb stick).

So steps if it's a hardware failure (requires 2nd computer)...

1. Determine whether the hard drive is an IDE or sata drive (see http://www.computer-hardware-explained.com/image-files/sata-vs-ide-labelled.jpg)
2. Take the hard drive, with the sata/ide cable out of the broken computer
3. Find a different computer who's motherboard supports sata/ide (as long as the computer isn't ancient it should support both).  Or, if you have a laptop, buy the adapter at the link above (or another adapter like it).
4. Plug the hard drive into the computer, either by opening up the working desktop computer's case and plugging in the sata/ide cable as well as the power cable, or using the usb adapter with the working laptop.
5. Browse to where the file is, copy it to the other drive (I might add back it up online somewhere).

Steps if it's a software issue

1. Download an ubuntu install disk (google ubuntu desktop iso)
2. Burn the install disk using imgburn from http://www.imgburn.com/index.php?act=download, or right click on it and click burn using windows built in image burner.
3. Put the ubuntu install disk into your dead computer, turn the power on a boot from the cd
4. When the ubuntu menu pops up, click the "Try Ubuntu" option (do NOT click install ubuntu, that will overwrite files)
5. When ubuntu loads, browse to the file on the hard drive and copy it to a usb stick.

*I suggested software's that I like, you can use whatever ones you want though.  You just need a live cd of an operating system and image burning software.
** I would have included more links but I didn't have high enough reputation, sorry.

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop
Link to ubuntu download location.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a Windows Vista Basic with intel processor that died with an
>   extremely important file on it and I'm changing to a Windows Vista
>   premium that uses AMD.

I would recommend that you get an external USB drive case that can handle your internal, place the drive in that case & then mount the drive on another system to retrieve the data you need.

In my experience the cost of the external USB case would be something like $20 at most. And the drive can then be read on most any other stable system. Get the data, reuse the drive if you wish—or just use it as an external drive now—and move on.

Answer (score 0):

How Can A new Motherboard Delete Old Hard disk the only possible way the hard will delete if it has 1 partition and you make a new installation on that partition but any hard disk with more than one partition can't be deleted , May Be you mean that your new motherboard use UEFI and if you don't use the BIOS legacy at UEFI that will change MBR to GPT and that may make loss for your partition table , If that's the problem you can use one of 2 method

1 - [change To legacy BIOS at UEFI](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825112.aspx)

2 - [convert MBR to GPT](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/convert-mbr-to-gpt-disk)

Note

There is an Article about "Windows Setup: Installing using the MBR or GPT partition style" can help at link 1